# Updates or creates an entity based on if a value is present in an Optional

Tags: java, functional-programming, optional, transactions

I need to get car info from a 3rd party web service and persist the data in my application DB. If my DB already has the car, I only update property values that may have changed. Otherwise, I create and save the car:

```
@Transactional //Spring Transaction
void saveCars() {

   //get CarInfo from a webservice
   List<CarInfo> carInfos = getCarInfo();

   // now get each Car from my application DB
   // that correspond to each CarInfo.
   Set<Car> cars = mySpringCarRepo.findByCarInfoIdIn(
       carInfos.stream().map(c -> c.getId())
           .collect(Collectors.toSet());

   for (CarInfo carInfo : carInfos) {

      // If a car for the carInfo 
      // is already in my application
      // just update it if some carInfo has changed.
      // If a car is not there, create and save it to DB.
      Car car = cars
                 .stream()
                 .filter(c -> c.getCarInfoId().equals(carInfo.getId())
                 .findAny()
                 .map(c -> updateCar(carInfo, car))
                 .orElseGet(() -> createCar(carInfo);

       mySpringCarRepo.save(car);
   }
}
```

I have the following questions / concerns about this code:

1. Is this an inappropriate use of `Optional`'s `map` method? I'm not mapping to a new object but rather just returning the same car with some properties potentially updated.
2. The save method is really only required to be called for cars created in the `orElseGet`. Due to being in a transaction, the updates to the car will be persisted without the save call. It seems redundant and perhaps confusing to call save.

Effective Java 3rd edition states that many uses of `isPresent` can profitably be replaced by other `Optional` methods. So that has led me to the path of using `map` & `orElseGet` and the fact that Java 8 does not have a `ifPresentOrElse` method on `Optional`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Regarding your questions

> Is this an inappropriate use of Optional's map method? I'm not mapping
> to a new object but rather just returning the same car with some
> properties potentially updated.

I think it's appropriate because it might return an updated object. Unfortunately (as you said) Java 8 doesn't have `ifPresentOrElse`.

> The save method is really only required to be called for cars created
> in the orElseGet.

You can change the `orElseGet` with `orElseGet(() -> mySpringCarRepo.save(createCar(carInfo)))` and remove the final save to the db.

### Performances

The complexity of the method is `O(c*ci)` where `c` is the number of cars in your DB and `ci` is the number of `CarInfo`.
If you store the Cars in a `Map` instead of a `Set` you can improve it to `O(ci)`.

```
void saveCars() {
    // get CarInfo from a webservice
    List<CarInfo> carInfos = getCarInfo();
    // Get cars from DB that correspond to each CarInfo
    Map<Long,Car> cars = mySpringCarRepo
            .findByCarInfoIdIn( getCarInfoIds(carInfos) )
            .stream()
            .collect( Collectors.toMap(Car::getCarInfoId,Function.identity()));
    
    for (CarInfo carInfo : carInfos) {
        // Returns Optional<Car>
        Optional.ofNullable(cars.get(carInfo.getId()))
        // Update car if already exists
        .map(c -> updateCar(carInfo, c))
        // Save car otherwise
        .orElseGet(() -> mySpringCarRepo.save(createCar(carInfo)));
    }
}
```

Or if you don't mind to query the db for each `CarInfo`, than the method is shorter:

```java
void saveCars() {
    getCarInfo().stream()
        .forEach(carInfo -> 
                    // returns Optional<Car>
                    mySpringCarRepo.findByCarInfoId(carInfo.getId()) 
                    // Update car if already exists
                    .map(car -> updateCar(carInfo, car))
                    // Save car otherwise
                    .orElseGet(() -> mySpringCarRepo.save(createCar(carInfo))));
}
```

**Note 1:** I haven't fully tested the code, it's just to give you an idea how to improve it.

**Note 2**: the performance gain might be irrelevant due to the DB and network latency, but with the second approach you should save some memory space.

### Naming

The method name `saveCars` is not very appropriate, a better name might be `updateCars` or `syncCars`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I replaced `orElseGet` with `OrElse`. I realized that after some troubleshooting and research that the code in the `OrElse` is executed even if the Optional is not empty (i.e. the `mySpringCarRepo.save(createCar(carInfo))` was executed for every car). I only bring this up for someone else reading / using the post. I know that you noted that you had not fully test the code. Thanks again for your very helpful answer.

Comment: @James my bad, I updated my answer. I replaced `orElse` with `orElseGet`.